# What is the meaning of the notation ${\cal O}_{\mathbb{CP}^n}(k)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, definition, riemann-surfaces

I am studying some papers in which the notation ${\cal O}_{\mathbb{CP}^1}(-1)$, ${\cal O}_{\mathbb{CP}^1}(-2)$ and ${\cal O}_{\mathbb{CP}^1}(1)$ appear. I am not familiar with that notation and while I have already found out ${\cal O}_{\mathbb{CP}^1}(-1)$ is the tautological line bundle, I haven't found what the others mean and want to understand this more generally, because surely there has to be some uniform definition that recovers the tautological line bundle as a special case.

I believe this is not special to $\mathbb{CP}^1$, and I also don't think there is something special about those numbers $-1,-2$ and $1$. So I imagine there is some general meaning for $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}^n}(k)$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

My question is: what does $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}^n}(k)$ mean and how to understand it? Is it really something defined for any $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ or for only some values like $-2,-1$ and $1$? If only for some numbers, why is it the case?

Comment: I believe it is [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01MM) notion, although I do not speak enough algebraic geometry to really make sense of it.

Comment: I'm kind of in the same situation. I have never studied algebraic geometry in detail, so I'm totally new to this. I found this while studying some problems in differential geometry and wanted to have a better understanding of it. It would be great if someone familiar with algebraic geometry could translate a bit of it. Thanks for the reference in any case, I'm trying to make sense of it.

Comment: You're probably going to have to study some algebraic geometry more to make them really visceral, but two down-to-earth-definitions:

- the bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is dual to the tautological bundle, and the bundle $\mathcal{O}(n)$ is the $n$th tensor power of the bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

- the bundle $\mathcal{O}(n)$ is the bundle whose sections over some open set $U$ are degree $n$ homogeneous rational functions whose denominator doesn't vanish along $U$. (To appreciate this one you need to be happy that a bundle is determined by its sheaf of sections.)

Comment: Thanks @hunter, that's great. These definitions do make it much clearer, but I will follow your advice and study some algebraic geometry to appreciate more what is going on. Do you have any nice reference to suggest? I found these lecture notes (https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf), but not sure it's the best place to study the subject...

Comment: Vakil's notes are great! But very long, as it's a thorough course in foundations, perhaps deeper foundations than you need if you only care about dimension one and the complex numbers. You can also try Rick Miranda's book on curves.

Comment: Or, given your background, go the complex geometry route. Consider Wells, Griffiths/Harris, or Huybrechts.

Comment: The notation is only sort of special to $\mathbb{P}^n$. Roughly, for any space embedded in complex projective space $i:X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ you may define $\mathcal{O}_X(n) = i^* \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(n)$. In the language of algebraic geometry, $X$ is a projective scheme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}\newcommand{\Sheaf}[1]{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^{1}}(#1)}$tl; dr: These bundles *are* defined for each integer, and over projective spaces of arbitrary dimension. Geometrically, *over the projective line*:

- The total space of $\Sheaf{-1}$ may be identified with the blow-up of $\Cpx^{2}$ at the origin. The fibres are lines through the origin, and the exceptional curve is the zero section.
- The total space of $\Sheaf{1}$ may be identified with a punctured complex projective plane. The fibres are lines through the puncture, an arbitrary line *not* through the puncture may be taken as the zero section, and projection away from the puncture is the bundle map.
- $\Sheaf{-2}$ is the cotangent (i.e., canonical) bundle. The total space may be viewed as the quotient of $\Cpx^{2}$ under scalar multiplication by $-1$, blown up at the origin.
- $\Sheaf{2}$ is the tangent (anticanonical) bundle. Its unit circle bundle may be identified more-or-less naturally with the matrix group $SO(3)$. (The first column of a real $3 \times 3$ special-orthogonal matrix may be viewed as a point of the unit sphere, indentified with the Riemann sphere; the second column is orthogonal to the first, hence an arbitrary unit tangent vector to the sphere in real Cartesian three-space; the third column is uniquely determined by the first two.)

---

In intrinsic detail, construct the projective line from two copies $U_{0}$ and $U_{1}$ of the complex line with coordinates $z^{0}$ and $z^{1}$. (It may be clearer at first to write $z = z^{0}$ and $w = z^{1}$. The indexing below generalizes to higher-dimensional projective spaces.)  For each integer $k$, the holomorphic line bundle $\Sheaf{k}$ may be trivialized over $U_{0}$ and $U_{1}$ by coordinates $(z^{0}, \zeta^{0})$ and $(z^{1}, \zeta^{1})$, glued together by the identification
$$
z^{0} = \frac{1}{z^{1}},\qquad
\zeta^{0} = \frac{\zeta^{1}}{(z^{1})^k}.
$$
That is, the transition function from $z^{0}$ to $z^{1}$ is
$$
g_{01}(z^{0}) = \frac{1}{(z^{0})^{k}}.
$$
A holomorphic section of $\Sheaf{k}$ is represented by holomorphic functions $\zeta^{0} = f_{0}(z^{0})$ and $\zeta^{1} = f_{1}(z^{1})$ satisfying
$$
g_{01}(z^{0}) f_{0}(z^{0}) = f_{1}(z^{1}).
$$